# REST API call from external system resetting the Case Owner back to Queue

Tags: apex

I am facing very weird issue. Salesforce has inbound integration with Oracle System. That system makes the REST API call and post the data. The moment they post data for some cases, the owner of the cases are getting reseted back to Queue.

The flow is

1. Requestor will create the case
2. Once case is successfully created, then case assigned to queue.
3. One member from the queue will work on the Case by taking ownership.

The moment rest call happens it reset the Owner back to queue.

I have InActivate all trigger, Process builder. What else and where I need to see to fixed this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was running into a similar issue myself about a month and a half ago.

Other things that can mess with the Case Owner are:

- Workflow Rules (with field updates)
- Case Assignment Rules

In my situation, the Cases I was creating were falling through to a default Case Assignment Rule that was overwriting the Owner that I was explicitly setting prior to the insert. My fix was to add a new Case Assignment Rule to specifically *not* change the owner in my particular situation.

With your case, I'd check for workflow rules first.

Comment: cool, I will check that first now. I will deactivate all and enable 1 by 1. Case Assignment Rule will not fire in my case, I think because they're calling at the time of Case insert only

Comment: Nope, its not working at all.

Comment: Could you please specify what you exactly added ?

Comment: @Kanika There's really not much more to explain. New Assignment Rule -> sort order = anything other than blank, criteria is specific to the org/situation, check "do not reassign owner"